# Unable to insert user into a specific OU when using GSuite's API

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-workspace

Might be a silly question, but I am banging my head against the desk with this one and can't seem to find the same question anywhere!

I've been tasked with pulling together a load of scripts to work with GSuite's API, basically to script out all the functions we want to do in batch.

I have one to create user's from CSV, and while it's creating the user, it's not setting the orgUnitPath variable to the string expected.

I've confirmed that it knows what the variable is supposed to be (a handy print call has shown me that when it's running) but it's landing top-level instead of into the area it's supposed to.

The code can be boiled down to this (I've left out the get_credentials and a few other steps as I know those are working...):

```
# Dict file so keywords can be used in CSV to call paths
orgunitDict = {'CS': 'Ops/CS', 'SM': 'Ops/SM', 'Accounts': 'Ops/Etc/Accounts'}

# Read CSV as dict
reader = csv.DictReader(inputfile)

# Iterate through rows of CSV creating user according to a combination of CSV data and fixed values (eg address type = work)
for row in reader:
    emailaddress = str(row['givenName']) + '.' + str(row['familyName']) + '@mydomain.co.uk'
    orgunitPath = orgunitDict[row['org']]
    userinfo = {'name': {'givenName': row['givenName'],
    'familyName': row['familyName']}, 'password': row['Password'], 'primaryEmail': emailaddress,
    'changePasswordAtNextLogin': 'TRUE', 'addresses': {'type': 'work', 'streetAddress': row['streetAddress']},
    'orgUnitPath': orgunitPath, 'organizations': {'title': row['Title']}, 'relations': {'type': 'manager', 'value': row['Manager']}
    }

    # Function to actually create the user
    user_request = service.users().insert(body=userinfo)
    user_request.execute()
    print(orgUnitPath)
```

Now that final print call is showing me, if 'CS' is the value in that row, the result 'Ops/CS', so the variable is setting correctly, but it isn't setting in the directory.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Thanks!

[using Python 3.6 by the way]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was just struggling to call the value from a dictionary as the value from a dictionary (I wanted to use the 'org' value from the row as the key to call the value from the dict orgunitDict).

Sorted by an intermediary step to assign that first key as a variable:
    # Dict file so keywords can be used in CSV to call paths
    orgunitDict = {'CS': 'Ops/CS', 'SM': 'Ops/SM', 'Accounts': 
    'Ops/Etc/Accounts'}

```
# Read CSV as dict
reader = csv.DictReader(inputfile)

# Iterate through rows of CSV creating user according to a 
combination of CSV data and fixed values (eg address type = work)
for row in reader:
    emailaddress = str(row['givenName']) + '.' + 
    str(row['familyName']) + '@mydomain.co.uk'

    orgrow = row['org']
    orgunitPath = orgunitDict[orgrow]
    userinfo = {'name': {'givenName': row['givenName'],
    'familyName': row['familyName']}, 'password': row['Password'], 
    'primaryEmail': emailaddress,
    'changePasswordAtNextLogin': 'TRUE', 'addresses': {'type': 
    'work', 'streetAddress': row['streetAddress']},
    'orgUnitPath': orgunitPath, 'organizations': {'title': 
    row['Title']}, 'relations': {'type': 'manager', 'value': 
    row['Manager']}
    }

    # Function to actually create the user
    user_request = service.users().insert(body=userinfo)
    user_request.execute()
    print(orgUnitPath)
    orgrow = row['org']
```